# Local Storage in JavaScript deleting all items instead of just one

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have been working on a vanilla JS project (no JQuery) and I am implementing local storage to save data on refresh. My below code is deleting all the items in the local storage array instead of the particular item I have set to be removed. Any help appreciated!

```js
function deleteItem(event)
{
    const item = event.target;
    const itemRemoveQuery = document.querySelector('.li-item');
    const itemRemove = itemRemoveQuery.innerHTML;

    if (item.classList[0] === "delete-btn")
    {
        const liItem = item.parentElement; 
        liItem.remove();
    }

    // Delete targeted item from local storage
    function removeLocalItems()
    {
        let items;
        let quantities;

        if (localStorage.getItem("items") === null || localStorage.getItem("quantities") === null)
        {
            items = [];
            quantities = [];
        }
        else
        {
            items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
            quantities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quantities"));
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            var quantityRemove = quantities[i];

            console.log(quantityRemove);
            if (items[i] == itemRemove)
            {
                localStorage.removeItem('items', 'itemRemove');
                localStorage.removeItem('quantities', 'quantityRemove')
            }
        }
    }

    removeLocalItems();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` only accepts one argument, which is the key of the item you want to remove: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

What you need to do instead is mutate the local `items` and `quantities` arrays (remove the appropriate items) that you parsed from `localStorage`, then do `localStorage.setItem('items', items)` and `localStorage.setItem('quantities', quantities)`.

Comment: Have to stringify those arrays in setItem

Comment: I have modified the code to do that and it appears that it is now working correctly. However, it is now throwing an error saying "Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0" on load and "Unexpected end of JSON input" when all items have been deleted. (The errors are at the other JSON.parse statements in the code). Is there any reason that this change would effect that?

Comment: I fixed these issues by deleting local storage if the arrays were empty. Thanks for your help!